# Using C# Nest API to get nested json data is not retrieving data

Tags: c#, json, nest, elasticsearch-plugin

I have the following json coming through the elasticsearch:

```
{
  "_index": "data-2016-01-14",
  "_type": "type-data",
  "_id": "AVJBBNG-TE8FYIA1rf1p",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "@message": {
      "timestamp": 1452789770326461200,
      "eventID": 1452789770326461200,
      "eventName": "New",
      "Price": "38.34",
      "Qty": 100,
      "statistic_LatencyValue_ns": 1142470,
      "statistic_LatencyViolation": false,
      "statistic_LossViolation": false
    },
    "@timestamp": "2016-01-14T16:42:50.326Z",
    "@fields": {
      "timestamp": "1452789770326"
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1452789770326
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using Nest to try to get the eventName data i created the class and marked the property:

```
public class ElasticTest
{
    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Nested)] 
    public string eventName { get; set; }
}
```

But the following query is returning 0 results, what am i doing wrong?

```
var result = client.Search<CorvilTest>(s => s
                    .From(0)
                    .Size(10000)
                    .Query(x => x
                    .Term(e => e.eventName,"New"))
                    );
                var r = result.Documents;
```

Mapping definition:

```
{
   "data-2016-01-14": {
      "mappings": {
         "type-data": {
            "properties": {
               "@fields": {
                  "properties": {
                     "timestamp": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "@message": {
                  "properties": {
                     "OrderQty": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "Price": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "eventID": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "eventName": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "statistic_LatencyValue_ns": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "statistic_LatencyViolation": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                     },
                     "statistic_LossViolation": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                     },
                     "timestamp": {
                        "type": "long"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "@timestamp": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please share the definition of `type-data` mapping.

Comment: How can i get this? I didn't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: Execute the Sense command `GET data-2016-01-14/_mapping/type-data` and share the output.

Comment: Here it is, thanks for the help!
{"data-2016-01-14":{"mappings":{"type-data":{"properties":{"@fields":{"properties":{"timestamp":{"type":"string"}}},"@message":{"properties":{"OrderQty":{"type":"long"},"Price":{"type":"string"},"eventID":{"type":"long"},"eventName":{"type":"string"},"statistic_LatencyValue_ns":{"type":"long"},"statistic_LatencyViolation":{"type":"boolean"},"statistic_LossViolation":{"type":"boolean"},"timestamp":{"type":"long"}}},"@timestamp":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"}}}}}}

Comment: Thank you for this information. I've added this information to the question and also tried to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the field `@message.eventName` is using a standard analyzer which means that its value is lower-cased and split at word boundaries before indexing. Hence the value "new" is indexed and not "New". Read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-beginner-troubleshooting#why-isnt-my-search-returning-what-i-expect). You need to be mindful about this fact when using a [`Term Query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html). Another thing is that the field `eventName` is not of `nested` type. So the code below should work for you.

```
var result = client.Search<CorvilTest>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10000)
    .Query(x => x
        .Term(e => e.Message.EventName, "new"))); // Notice I've used "new" and not "New"

var r = result.Documents;
```

For the above code to work the definition of `CorvilTest` class should be something like below:

```
public class CorvilTest
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "@message")]
    public Message Message { get; set; }

    /* Other properties if any */
}

public class Message
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "eventName")]
    public string EventName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In this case in the code the Term contains e, as i can see e is type of message so it should be e.Message.eventName, right?

Comment: Did you specify the correct index name and type name in your Nest query?

Comment: Sorry, i had a issue with the elastic search it's working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Weird, but it didn't work this is what i specified:
var node = new Uri("http://199.53.249.185:9200");
                var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, "data-2016-01-15");
                settings.MapDefaultTypeIndices(d => d.Add(typeof(CorvilTest), "type-data"));
                var client = new ElasticClient(settings);